# Fail to check if dropdown menu contains some text using selenium

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I did it before and it worked but now the dropdown html/css id a bit different and I cant get it to work right.

This is the hierarchy for the dropdown code, and I marked for example what text I want to know if exist:

[image]

So what I did it set up a web element of the button that opens the dropdown, get its text and checking if it contains some text:

```
val myDropDown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("""//*[@id="no-jcf"]/div[2]/div[3]/form/div[18]/div[2]/div[2]/ol/button"""))
val ans = myDropDown.getText().contains("Copy of Invoice")
```

Its not working. I get a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for a specific option then u can try this :

```
WebElement myDropDown=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'dropdown-toggle')]//li[@data-value='8']//span[1]"));
String dropdownText=myDropDown.getText();
if(dropdownText.equalsIgnoreCase("Copy of Invoice"))
{
//...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 main mistakes:

1) Your xpath leads to button, but that button is not parent of the dropdown. Dropdown is its next sibling. That means you are then trying to get text from button, not options in dropdown.

2) `getText()` gets the **visible** inner text of element and its subelements so make sure your options are visible (with click or mouseover)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to set collection off webelements and found the one you need
for example:

```
List<WebElement> liCollection =
driver.findElement(By.Id("no-jcf").findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

now you have all the collection of li elements that under the special id
so you just need do to for/foreach and check if that element is what you need

```
for(WebElement li : liCollection )
{
   if(li.getText().contains("Copy of Invoice"))
   {
   //...
   }
}
```